# android transition from landscape view to portrait view

Tags: android

I have an activity which is in landscape orientation. When i press back, it goes to portrait view. I want to create a transition from left to right. I tried overridePendingTransition(anim.slide_in_left, anim.slide_out_right);.. still transition is not correct.pls Help

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

 public class TeeenAni extends Activity {

ViewFlipper flipper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    Animation hyperspaceJump = 
     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.);
    image.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
   flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.anim.hyperspace_jump);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01); 

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
}
    private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {


        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

        inFromRight.setDuration(500);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {

        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
    }

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {

        Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
        inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromLeft;
    }

    private Animation outToRightAnimation() {

        Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        outtoRight.setDuration(500);
        outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoRight;
    }
```

Comment: is there any other way than using animation... it works fine when we move from portrait view to portrait view.